# What is the element of deciding whether is the present perfect continuous tense?

Tags: grammar

A: How long ___ (you / build) your new house?

B: About three months.

In this case, what is the element of deciding whether is the present perfect continuous tense?

Why can’t it use the present perfect simple?

I thought that I was able to use present perfect tense in here. Like ‘How long have you built your new house. Because my opinion was that house was already built. I know that present perfect simple is more relative to explain completed things than present perfect continuous tense.

So the thing what I want to ask you guys, is there something to decide if it is present perfect or not?

Comment: If the house is already finished, also consider the simple past: *How long did it take you to build your new house?*

Comment: Or _How long is it since you built/finished building your new house?_ My guess is that the house is not finished and the question is meant to be _How long have you been building [it]?_